# OSUmicro benchmarks and segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, latency, openmpi, microbenchmark

I have a three-node cluster, based on rhel 6.1

on every node i have two CPU and 4 GPU  Tesla M2090/

I use Openmpi 1.6.1, which works fine( system tested on GPU Linpak ver.).

And i install mvapich2 1.9 and i have the same problem.

I think that the trouble maybe in this test?!

Cuda ver 5.0

Infiniband - MEllanox.

Compiling of this bechmark was succesfull, and when i start point to point using only CPU (H to H) (both localhost and two nodes):

> mpirun -np 2 ./osu_latency H H

it's work fine. But when i use the GPU(copy from CPU to GPU mem):

> mpirun -np 2 ./osu_latency H D

the program crashes with **segmentation fault(11)**.

I compile this benchmark, ver 3.7 from http://www.nersc.gov/assets/Trinity--NERSC-8-RFP/Benchmarks/Dec17/OMB-NERSC8.tar, using these parameters:

> --prefix=/usr/local/bench/osu
>   --enable-cuda --with-cuda=/usr/local/cuda-5.0 --with-cuda-include=/usr/local/cuda-5.0/include --with-cuda-libpath=/usr/local/cuda-5.0 CC=/usr/local/mpi/openmpi16/bin/mpicc

I try to run program with absolete path, but it has no effect.

Where is the problem?
Thank in Advance!